# How reauthentication is handled in current modern web application

Tags: security, web-applications

In our web application, when a user logs in, if the session is idle for longer than 15 minutes, the user has to enter the login credentials again to continue.

As I do not use other web applications I would like to ask the following questions concerning this matter:

Is such a reauthentication usual in current web applications?

After how many minutes inactivity does it come?

From a security standpoint, is it common and reasonable to only ask for the password (and not the user name again)?

If you fail to reauthenticate (3 times), is it more common to only end the session or lock the whole account?

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: Good question, I will post my answer shortly. Hand on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Is such a reauthentication usual in current web applications?***
Yes it is. Most web applications that have access to valuable data implement the reauthentication mechanism to prevent information leak.

***After how many minutes inactivity does it come?*** Depends on the application and the sensitivity of the data you're protecting. The normal timout is 15 to 20 minutes (Its even lesser in Banking web apps)

***From a security standpoint, is it common and reasonable to only ask for the password (and not the user name again)?*** "Login" refers to a correct *combination* of username and password. Most web apps will ask you for the username again. Unless that is you have the "Remember my username" option enabled. This is because a malicious user can potentially get your username after accessing the web app after your session timed out. If he also manages to get his hands on your email (which is usually linked to your username), he can easily reset your password and do whatever he wishes with your account

***If you fail to reauthenticate (3 times), is it more common to only end the session or lock the whole account?*** This too depends on the application.

Data is very valuable -> Lock the account

Not so much-> End session and force Reauthentication (3 more tries)

Best of both worlds-> Timeout the username for a fixed duration (Ranges from half an hour to a couple of hours) and then force reauthentication.

Answer (score 2):

Re-Authentication

Re-authentication is the process of making a secondary confirmation of a person’s identity after checking previously. Usually a user has to perform an additional login by force to ensure that a user who is accessing a protected resource is the same person who initially authenticated at the start of the session. Forced re-authentication provides additional protection for sensitive resources in the secure domain.

Authentication is token based. Rest APIs are designed with this too, and can sometimes perform re-authentication.

Of course, sessions are used.

Answer (score 1):

Session times out usually at 15 to 20 minutes depending what it's set to in IIS. That is a reasonable idle time for a user to be logged off. If you need your application to sit idle and still be usable for longer periods than that you'll want to look into token authentication (stateless) and using refresh tokens.